# How to convert "A" to Row1Column1 in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I execute my query, and starting for example "B3" I start inserting the data. The problem is that I insert the data cell by cell.
How can I convert my "B3" to Row2Column3 in C#?
I saw people using `Application.ConvertFormula` but I cant find the reference for Application, cuz if I do Application. -  I have no ConvertFormula..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: Found a piece of code tha converts a column letter to column int: 

`public int ExcelColumnToNumber(string pColonne)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pColonne)) throw new ArgumentNullException("columnName");

            pColonne = pColonne.ToUpperInvariant();

            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < pColonne.Length; i++)
            {
                sum *= 26;
                sum += (pColonne[i] - 'A' + 1);
            }

            return sum;
        }`